# How to display error message when clicking button - not using forms - HTML, Python

Tags: python, html, mysql, sql

I am building a movie application. I have set up a movie page with brief details about the movie and 2 button: Watched and Saved, which can save into a users watched list or save for later list.
I have set up my backend so that if a user clicks on the watched or saved button more than once, it should not save the movie to the database table watchedmovies or savedmovies. However i am struggling to display an error message.

Backend Code for watched button snippet:

```
    cursor.execute( "SELECT * FROM watchedmovies WHERE username LIKE %s", [username_new] )
        watched_post = cursor.fetchone()
        print(watched_post)
        message = ""
        if watched_post:
            message = "You have already saved this movie to your watched list!"
            return redirect(url_for('movie', id=id))
        else:
            cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO watchedmovies VALUES (% s, % s, % s)', (watched_username, id, watched_title))
            mysql.connection.commit()
            message = 'This movie has been saved to your watched list!' 
        return redirect(url_for('user', id=id, username_new=username_new, current_post=current_post, profile_post=profile_post, watched_post=watched_post, message=message))
```

Front end - HTML code for the movie page where for the watched button:

```
<div class="message">{{ message }}</div>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{{ url_for('watched', id=current_post.id, username_new=profile_post.username)}}">Watched</a>
```

I dont really know what I am doing wrong. I have tried using a flash message but that didnt work either.
I am just looking to flash a message when a user clicks on the watched button to try and save a movie they have already saved

Comment: The `if` block doesn't return `message` (you just assign its value), as opposed to the `else` block (its indentation is off, though)

Comment: Please provide some additional information about the backend and frontend frameworks that you are using! E.g. the curly brackets could be something like vue.js and the redirect(url_for()) something like flask. Please add the corresponding tags to your question!

Comment: You sent  `message`  to `user`, but you haven't sent  `message`  to the page. Pay attention to the parameter transmission relationship

Answer (score 0):

For python, you could use this to display an error message.

```
try:
    a=input()
except:
    raise Exception('Movie Already Saved')
```

You could change it slightly to fit your code, for instance, by making a variable that keeps track of if the movie is saved or not. Then, if it is, you could just display the error message you want.

Ex:

```
Aladin_already_saved=False
def movie_saved(x):
    if movie_save_button_clicked:
        if x==True:
            print("This movie is already saved")
        else:
            print("Movie successfully saved")
movie_saved(Aladin_already_saved)
```

It isn't the most convenient way to do it, as you would have to make it the first variable like Cats_already_saved, and run this line for every movie you want to add, but I assume you aren't going to have a catalog as large as something like Netflix, so this should work for you if you adjust it slightly.

Comment: Cheers! Good luck on your movie site!